# Setting string limit when creating Postgresql model in command line for Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, command-line, rails-activerecord

First question posted on here so all feedback welcome in terms of etiquette etc!

I am trying to create my db model in command line. I am working in Rails 4:

```
bin/rails g model item name:string description:text price:integer
```

However, I am looking to put a limit on the name. I think I need

```
limit:50
```

however, I cannot get the syntax correct. I keep setting up a new property called '50' which is of type 'limit' or it gets ignored completely. I have tried:

```
bin/rails g model item name:string:limit:50 description:text price:integer
bin/rails g model item name:(string, limit:50) description:text price:integer
bin/rails d model item name:string limit:50, description:text price:integer
```

but without success.

Also, cheeky to add on a second part of this question,but Postgresql documentation suggests I can use a type 'money' for the 'price' property but Active Record doesn't like this. Am I right to use 'integer'?

Thanks in advance!
HatStephens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I have got this working?

```
bin/rails g model item name:string{50} description:text price:integer
```

Maybe this will help someone one day! Or I can search for it when I forget next time!